# Cannot launch a x86_64 AVD on Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, qemu, avd-manager

I have no problems launching a x86 AVD from Android Studio or with a command line, but x86_64 images have zero effects. No error message, no nothing.

```
geecko@arch emulator: ./emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30 # This is the x86 AVD
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_21155.ini
WARNING | Not saving state: RAM not mapped as shared
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint


geecko@arch emulator: ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_31 # This is the x86_64 AVD
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 geecko@unknown]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,port=43549,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem: address resolution failed for ::1:43549: Name or service not known
```

After that, nothing happens.

> QEMU emulator version 6.1.0
>
> HAXM v7.5.6.r9.g7f3aaab-1
>
> Linux arch 5.15.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 08 Dec 2021 14:33:16 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

For my case the problem was that I turned off IPv6 at the first time OS configuration.
You need to enable it and emulator will be working.