# Android Studio Emulator not starting without internet connection (linux)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I am using parrot OS. It is a Debian-based operating System. I installed android studio.
If I run the emulator when I am connected to the internet then it works fine but when I run it without the internet then it doesn't work. I tried to run it using an emulator then I saw some logs

**Here are the Logs**:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /home/ak/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
ERROR   | Failed to retrieve DNS servers list from the system
WARNING | Cannot find system DNS servers! Name resolution will be disabled.
WARNING | cannot add library /home/ak/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/ak/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 ak@unknown]
INFO    | injectedQemuChannel!
INFO    | Informing listeners of injection.
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,port=44369,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem: address resolution failed for ::1:44369: Name or service not known
```

***Can't we use the android studio emulator without the internet?***

Answer (score 1):

What works for a number of us experiencing this problem, including me, is [disabling IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991760/17994624):

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

or [just on the loopback interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795602/17994624):

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

[For](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215231636) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684929/cannot-launch-a-x86-64-avd-on-linux), however, doing the opposite apparently fixes the problem: enabling IPv6 where it has been disabled.